# Как написать регулярное выражение для поиска не пустой строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно регулярное выражение, которое подходит для не пустой строки, и не состоящей только из пробелов и переносов строки. При этом, если в строке есть любой другой символ, не зависимо от расположение, допускается уже любое количество пробелов, переносов и тд. Я дошел до такого выражения "'.*\S.'" но оно не пропускает строку если в нем есть пробелы.
Примеры: текст текст, текст текст, текст, текст , вместо "текст" любой не пробельный символ и не перенос строки
В коде он будет в таком виде:

```
description: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Описание',
      pattern: '^(?!\s+$)[\w\W]+',
    }
```

Comment: Может, `^(?!\s+$)[\w\W]+`?

Comment: `[^\s]+` все кроме пробельных символов с квантификатором 1 или более

Comment: @ipatev_nn Пропускает строку только из нескольких пробелов подряд

Comment: @lian.lun, странное поведение, воспользуйтесь тогда примером от Виктора, но у меня такого поведения не наблюдается: https://regex101.com/r/fafSvF/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Не подходит, не пропускает строки если в них есть пробел

Comment: Пример приведите.

Comment: И укажите тогда язык на котором используете регулярные выражения

Comment: Примеры: текст текст, текст        текст,               текст, текст           , вместо "текст" любой не пробельный символ и не перенос строки, пишу в javascript

Comment: А почему нельзя просто применить `trim` к строке и посмотреть его длину?

Comment: @EzioMercer Нужна именно регулярка

Comment: Вы не удвоили символы обратной косой черты. `pattern: '^(?!\\s+$)[\\w\\W]+',` должно быть. Собственно, может, подойдёт и `pattern: '^\\s*\\S[^]*',`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Так работает, спасибо, добавьте ответ, отмечу

Comment: Да, но ведь ваш `pattern: '.*\\S.*',` тоже работает? Или у вас нет последнего `*`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew нет последнего *, да и слэш не удвоен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не забывайте, что в строковых литералах в JavaScript символ обратной косой черты используется для определения escape-последовательностей (экранированных) вроде `\n` (LF), `\t` (TAB), `\r` (CR) и так далее.

Вам подойдут

```js
pattern: '.*\\S.*',
pattern: '^(?!\\s+$)[\\w\\W]+',
pattern: '^\\s*\\S[^]*',
```

Первое выражение находит строки с как минимум одним непробельным символом.

Второе выражение находит целую строку (даже с переводами строки), которая не состоит целиком из пробельных символов.

Последнее выражения находит целую строку (даже с переводами строки), которая содержит мимимум один непробельный символ. По сути, это то же выражение, что и первое, но эффективнее.